# OSError: [Errno None not found] 2 - error when launching jupyter on Windows

Tags: python, jupyter

I am on Win 10 machine, I have Python 3.4 installed. I installed jupyter `pip install jupyter` successfully. But when I issue command `jupyter python` I get the following error message:

```
D:\..\Python>jupyter python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\jupyter.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 186, in main
    _execvp(command, sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 104, in _execvp
    raise OSError('%r not found' % cmd, errno.ENOENT)
OSError: [Errno None not found] 2
```

How do I troubleshoot?

**Update**

Ok, I installed Anaconda to make my life easier, but still when I issue `jupyter python` I get the same error as above. How can I point to correct jupyter (the one that came with Anaconda)?

Comment: try `$> jupyter notebook`

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde Thank you very much, I lost my mind! I am going to take a nap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running

```
jupyter notebook
```

runs a webservice which you then connect to in a browser, as [localhost:8888](http://localhost:8888) (unless you change the default port). 
You can then open a notebook or iPython file there.

Don't try to run `jupyter python` or `jupyter script.ipynb` otherwise you'll get the `not found` error

Answer (score 1):

try to use below command:

> jupyter-notebook